# SSH use only my password, Ignore my ssh key, don't prompt me for a passphrase

Tags: ssh, authentication, password

This is a question regarding the OpenSSH client on Linux, MacOSX and FreeBSD.

Normally, I log into systems using my SSH key.

Occasionally, I want my SSH client to ignore my SSH key and use a password instead. If I 'ssh hostname', my client prompts me for the Passphrase to my SSH key which is an annoyance. Instead, I want the client to simply ignore my SSH key, so that the server will ask me for my password instead.

I tried the following, but I am still prompted for the passphrase to my SSH key. After this, I am prompted for my password.

```
ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=password host.example.org
```

I want to do this on the client side, without any modification of the remote host.

Answer (score 272, accepted):

Try `ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=yes -o PreferredAuthentications=keyboard-interactive,password -o PubkeyAuthentication=no host.example.org`

In ssh v2, `keyboard-interactive` is another way to say "password".  The `-o PubkeyAuthentication=no` option instructs the client not to attempt key pair authentication.

In addition, the `PasswordAuthentication=yes` option is to override any previously configured ssh options that may have disabled it.

Comment: And in fact 'ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=keyboard-interactive host' also works.

I was thrown off by SSH_CONFIG(5), which still mentions the 'password' keyword.

Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Correction: In SSH v2, **both** `password` and `keyboard-interactive` are valid, and they are different things. (`password` requires a password, and `keyboard-interactive` can technically be anything.)

Comment: Bill could you update your answer according to grawity's comment?

Look at the output of these commands:
    
    lucian@XXX:~$ ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=keyboard-interactive -o PubkeyAuthentication=no host.example.org
    Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password).

    lucian@XXX:~$ ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=password -o PubkeyAuthentication=no host.example.org
    lucian@host.example.org's password:

Comment: What does your server configuration look like? I've never seen that difference. As well, that wouldn't answer the original question, they were trying password.

Comment: If you want to add this switch to ssh's config file (~/.ssh/config) it's PubkeyAuthentication no in that file.

Comment: `ssh -o PubkeyAuthentication=no  host.example.org` worked for me, when ssh from debian to other debian. fyi

Comment: Bingo, this works brilliantly

Comment: I googled many phrases before I finally found this under `ssh don't send key`. Wow, this is hard to find.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I still get *Permission denied (publickey).* Looks like it's refusing to do anything else on the server end.

Comment: This works with ssh-copy-id as well, thanks for the answer!

Comment: This works for scp as well

Comment: Works for me. Another solution is the option `-o IdentitiesOnly=yes`.

Comment: Note to self - if you get intermittent key exchange failure, it's nothing to do with the key. The VM is out of memory and needs rebooting!