# ssh to same host from 2 different clients, not same list of authentication methods?

Tags: ssh, authentication, password, dropbear

I have a usb gadget exposing itself as network card,
and allowing to ssh to it.

From my laptop I can authenticate using [password method](https://serverfault.com/questions/130346/ssh-use-only-my-password-ignore-my-ssh-key-dont-prompt-me-for-a-passphrase?rq=1):

```
$ ssh -v -v -v -o PreferredAuthentications=password -o PubkeyAuthentication=no root@10.11.99.1 
...
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
```

But the same device connected to my desktop, won't allow password method

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
```

In both case I am using the same ssh client `ssh -V`:

```
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
```

I would assume difference should be on the server host (the gadget).
It uses dropbear, but I didn't found any specific configuration.

From where could come this different behavior in Authentication method available?

Comment: Different ssh client configurations on laptop and desktop? Maybe password authentication is simply disabled on desktop? Check config files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What puzzled me was the different behavior of the ssh client targeting what I believed to be the same server, as I am not aware of configuration file on client side to specify the list of authentication method.

But I was wrong:
the network configuration of the usb device was wrong in the desktop case (wrong gateway). Which caused the ssh command on the desktop to connect to a different ssh server, which was rightly configured to reject password authentication.